# interactive code editor for a website

Tags: php, jquery, scripting

i want to create an interactive code editor for my website,that people visit and try different language code and the online code editor interact with the person if he did something wrong and i was searching using Google to get some answers but didn't find any or i am unable to ask correct question! (so sorry for that and also for my English or something else),so i am here for the question which i need answer.

I need a script which can perform all the function/which i can implement in my website. OR

if you know the name of the scripts tell me i will buy it to implement it on my website. OR

you can give me a rough idea how i can create interactive code editor and the rest i will do.

Thank you for help and is my question in appropriate to ask?? than reply me in comment.

Comment: Hmm... there are tonns of links in google. Try to type "web code editor"

Comment: web code editor doesn't work for me..
what i need is here..you can check using this url.i want to implement this functionality in my wordpress website.checkout this link : http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-HZA3b/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b

    or this one :     http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/1?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8

or some alternative to tis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language would you do to test their code online? php?

For syntax coloring online via a textarea you can use http://codemirror.net/

Basically you want to do this => http://www.compileonline.com/?

Comment: wow..thank's :)
yes i want to implement the online compiler.is there any code available that i should implement this in my website? basically my website is based on wordpress?

Comment: i want to test multiple language..because i have different courses and i want to implement this function for all of my courses.

Comment: In terms of css and html you should not have any problem in some line of code you can get the input of the visitor and implemented to show the end result. 
Then for php and javascript is a bit more complicated security level! 
You can not accept all the native functions of language genre exec () or system () .. 

Ditto for other programming languages​​. For c / perl / python / java EE / and others ... You will have then probably went through CGI.